# Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, github, jenkins

I'd like for Jenkins to automagically fetch data from my private repository hosted on Github.
But I have no idea how to accomplish that task.. Tried the documentation, generating ssh-key for jenkins user and all what I can see is: "unable to clone the repo". I've checked URLs - they are valid.

Any clues, maybe you know some docs/blogs/whatever which are describing this kind of stuff?

Comment: I answer this a similar question, you can see the answer in the link below: [jenkins & GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515039/jenkins-git-permission-denied-publickey/8143432#8143432)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Perhaps GitHub's support for [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) is what you're looking for?  To quote that page:

> **When should I use a deploy key?**
>
> Simple, when you have a server that needs pull access to a single private repo. This key is attached directly to the repository instead of to a personal user account.

If that's what you're already trying and it doesn't work, you might want to update your question with more details of the URLs being used, the names and location of the key files, etc.

---

Now for the technical part: How to use your SSH key with Jenkins?

If you have, say, a `jenkins` unix user, you can store your deploy key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. When Jenkins tries to clone the repo via ssh, it will try to use that key.

In some setups, you cannot run Jenkins as an own user account, and possibly also cannot use the default ssh key location `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. In such cases, you can create a key in a different location, e.g. `~/.ssh/deploy_key`, and configure `ssh` to use that with an entry in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host github-deploy-myproject
    HostName       github.com
    User           git
    IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/deploy_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Because all you authenticate to all Github repositories using `git@github.com` and you don't want the above key to be used for all your connections to Github, we created a host alias *github-deploy-myproject*. Your clone URL now becomes

```
git clone github-deploy-myproject:myuser/myproject
```

and that is also what you put as *repository URL* into Jenkins.

(Note that you must *not* put *ssh://* in front in order for this to work.)

Comment: Yeah - already managed to solve my problem - I've added ssh key directly to the repo (as deploy key) and not to the account as before.

Comment: Bur how do you created a key for jenkins?

Comment: The "deploy key" is just any old SSH key. What I did is run `ssh-keygen` as the user Jenkins runs as ("jenkins" on my Ubuntu server). I then added `~jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the deploy keys section of the repository on github.

Comment: This answer doesn't help much. Looking for the process of making the keys particularly. I think that you have to login as whatever system account tomcat/jenkins is running as and gen the keys then scoop them up out of /var/empty.

Comment: on some installs you would need to out this not into `~` directory. But into `/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/` for the default jenkins user to use those keys!

Comment: To follow up on the comment by @garmoncheg, note that `/var/lib/jenkins` *is* the home directory (`~`) for the `jenkins` user.

Comment: Any clue how to use this method when updating submodules for `myuser/myproject` ?? opened up a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25535632/loading-private-repository-submodules-in-jenkins-project

Comment: Does anyone know how to get deploy hooks working with this? I'm seeing errors akin to `Could not match github-deploy-myproject:myuser/myproject` in the hook log. I've entered that as my Repo URL and builds do work so it can access GitHub. It's just the post from GitHub that fails to trigger the build.

Comment: To be clear, this solution does not currently work with Github Post-hooks, so triggering jobs does not work. - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18298

Comment: @pogo I found that triggering builds using the github plugin seemed to require that the Repository URL matched the SSH clone URL, as the plugin seems to reconstruct that URL from the post-hook and trigger builds that have a matching repository URL. I have multiple projects, so ended up creating a dummy user with a single SSH key and access to all the private repos, rather than a deployment key, but I suspect changing `Host github-deploy-myproject` to `Host github.com` and using `git@github.com:myuser/myproject` for repository URL may be what you need (based on my setup, YMMV of course)

Answer (score 37):

One thing that got this working for me is to make sure that `github.com` is in `~jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having where after setting up a key pair, a git push was failing

Comment: In my case the easiest way to do this is to do 'sudo su jenkins' as it isn't possible to log in as the jenkins user properly. Once you have the jenkins identity, you can do a manual ssh login to github/bitbucket and accept the remote host key on behalf of the jenkins user.

Comment: But what if you making Jenkins Initialization part of your development environment 'bootstrap'. The 'manual' aspect of this doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

If you need Jenkins to access more then 1 project you will need to:
1. add public key to one github user account 
2. add this user as Owner (to access all projects) or as a Collaborator in every project.

Many public keys  for one system user will not work because GitHub will find first matched deploy key and will send back error like **"ERROR: Permission to user/repo2 denied to user/repo1"**

http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Comment: The answer about using a deploy key works great if you just have a single repository.  But when you want a CI server to build projects across multiple repos you're immediately in the position of managing several sets of keys (one pair per repo) and it becomes much easier to take the approach listed in this answer.

Comment: This guy's guide explains how to set it via different deploy keys using ~/.ssh/config : https://gist.github.com/victorborda/2871029

Comment: @JorgeOrpinel, I believe the approach in the link can prevent github webhooks from triggering builds using the Github plugin. I found a dummy user with a single key and access to all of the repos worked better when I also wanted builds to be triggered by a webhook, because I needed the Repository URL in the build config to match the github clone URL, see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository#comment47182184_5212358)

Answer (score 7):

Jenkins creates a user Jenkins on the system. The ssh key must be generated for the Jenkins user. 
Here are the steps:

```
sudo su jenkins -s /bin/bash
cd ~
mkdir .ssh // may already exist
cd .ssh
ssh-keygen
```

Now you can create a Jenkins credential using the SSH key
On Jenkins dashboard
Add Credentials

select this option

> Private Key: From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with gitlab. It turns out I had restricted the users that are allowed to login via ssh. This won't affect github users, but in case people end up here for gitlab (and the like) issues, ensure you add `git` to the `AllowUsers` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
AllowUsers batman git
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [GitHub personal access tokens](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line):

- Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new
- Add **repo** scope
- In Jenkins, add a **GitHub** source
- Use Repository HTTPS URL
- Add the **HTTPS** URL of the git repo (not the **SSH** one, eg. `https://github.com/my-username/my-project.git`)
- Add credential

  - Kind: Username with Password
  - Username: the GitHub username
  - Password: **the personal access token you created on GitHub**
  - ID: something like `github-token-for-my-username`

I tested this on Jenkins ver. 2.222.1 and Jenkins GitHub plugin 1.29.5 with a private GitHub repo.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to the answer from sergey_mo is to create multiple ssh keys on the jenkins server.

(Though as the first commenter to sergey_mo's answer said, this may end up being more painful than managing a single key-pair.)

Comment: Now I see why simply posting a URL is a terrible strategy for answers.  The link above is dead.