# How can I trigger Jenkins builds from multiple private GitHub repositories?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I've got a Jenkins box configured to build multiple projects that are hosted privately on GitHub. Each project has been assigned its own deploy key and is aliased via `~/.ssh/config` as mentioned in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)

However, now I'm trying to setup triggered builds through the GitHub plugin's web hook at `https://user:pass@myci.example.com/github-webhook`, but it looks like I'm running into issues since my jobs are configured with repositories such as `github-my-project:zacharydanger/my-project.git` and the plugin's not recognizing them because it's trying to match it as `git@github.com:zacharydanger/my-project.git`.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Looks like there's no *workaround*, but [this GitHub support page about managing deploy keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys) says that you can just create a user account for deploying. So I've added Jenkins' default public key to an account and given it pull access to the private repos it needs to build.