# Jenkins Build Error using GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, windows-server-2008

I've recently been tasked with deriving a CI solution using Jenkins, GitHub, and Windows Server 2008  which is configured to use the Git executable (under the Manage Jenkins -> Configure System tab):

`C:\msysgit\git-cmd.bat`

While the wiki article link provides a bit of insight, I'm getting the following error:

```
Building in workspace C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\{job name}\workspace
Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\{job name}\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@5a969ec9
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:{git repo}.git
git --version
Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
Fetching upstream changes from origin
FATAL: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. See [same wiki link] for more information
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revParse(CliGitAPIImpl.java:265)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.revParse(GitAPI.java:252)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getHeadRevision(DefaultBuildChooser.java:95)
    at hudson.plugins.git.util.DefaultBuildChooser.getCandidateRevisions(DefaultBuildChooser.java:87)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1051)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:904)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:877)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:942)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1108)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1369)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1575)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:241)
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you use the **[Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)** for that, instead of trying to call it from a script.
Also, you will probably need to set an SSH key for that, and configure it in Jenkins.

See also here:

- [Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)
- [Setup Jenkins for working with a private Github repository](https://github.com/Tozkoparan/Deneme/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-for-working-with-a-private-Github-repository)