# Loading private repository submodules in Jenkins Project

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys

I'm currently stuck trying to get Jenkins to

- clone a project and it's submodules
- use the deploy key config as per [Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)

Here is my output from Jenkins Console.. it's obvious the plugin is attempting to use the straight project name.. which is not setup to use the key.

```
  Started by user '__'
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/JENKINSPROJECTNAME
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.PROJECTREPO.url github-deploy-project:Owner/ProjectName # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from github-deploy-project:Owner/ProjectName
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress github-deploy-project:Owner/ProjectName +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/ProjectName/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/ProjectName/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/ProjectName/ProjectName/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ______________ (refs/remotes/ProjectName/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f _____________
 > git rev-list ________________ # timeout=10
 > git remote # timeout=10
 > git submodule init # timeout=10
 > git submodule sync # timeout=10
 > git config --get remote.ProjectName.url # timeout=10
 > git submodule update --init --recursive
FATAL: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into 'submodule/FolderName'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Owner/SubModuleProject.git/'
Clone of 'https://github.com/Owner/SubModuleProject.git' into submodule path 'submodule/FolderName' failed

hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive" returned status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into 'submodule/FolderName'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Owner/SubModuleProject.git/'
Clone of 'https://github.com/Owner/SubModuleProject.git' into submodule path 'submodule/FolderName' failed

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1407)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$6.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:742)
    at hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.SubmoduleOption.onCheckoutCompleted(SubmoduleOption.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:920)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1252)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:615)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:524)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1706)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:232)
```

Answer (score 1):

Git is recursively fetching the repos defined in .gitmodules at the base of the main project.

You have a couple of ways to attack this:

- Change .gitmodules to refer to a copy of the repo with required
  access controls.
- Fork the github repo, and change the required access
  controls.
- Remove the entry in .submodule and instead copy it into the
  main repo.
- If you control the github repo in question, configure
  ~jenkins/.ssh/config IdentityFile