# How to configure Ubuntu 14.04 Jenkins to connect to GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins

UPDATE:

I found the answer.  You can't use a pass phrase when you generate the key.  (It's an easy mistake to make, since the GitHub instructions strongly suggest that you do use a pass phrase.  Presumably the case of deploy keys is an exception).

---

Have been trying to setup a Jenkins server on Ubuntu 14.04.  Have installed Jenkins no problems, but am unable to connect to the secure repository URL.  I'm getting permission denied (public key).  I have tried a lot of solutions that I researched on the web, but still no success.

Here are the details:

- Jenkins installed no problems and running as user jenkins
- GitHub plugin is installed
- Have followed the github instructions on keygen.  I tried this as my own user (kim) on the ubuntu machine, and have also done it as the jenkins user
- Am loading the public key as a deploy key against the github repo
- Am loading the private key directly in the credentials in jenkins
- Have tried numerous different usernames in the Jenkins credentials setup (including git, git@github.com, and my git hub user name)
- The authentication test (ssh -T git@github.com) works no bother
- I have tried this solution, [Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository).  Again, the ssh test works fine (against the alias), but Jenkins still fails

I'm running out of ideas?

Comment: By username, are you talking about the username field in the ssh-agent plugin? (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin)