# Jenkins can''t connect to Git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, vagrant

I'm trying to set up `Jenkins` referencing a `Git` repository. However I get this strange error

[image]

Any idea what is wrong. The repository works fine on my team mates computers.

Comment: What credentials is Jenkins using to connect?  This is the first place I'd look if your "mates' " have access.

Comment: They are using no credentials just like me.

Comment: You are incorrect.  I just tried to edit `Hangman.java` from GitHub and I was told that I do not have write access.  You are definitely using credentials to access this repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your "mates" have access to the `Goatic/hangman` git repository, Jenkins does not as it is running under a different user.  You can add credentials from the Jenkins admin screen by doing *Manage Jenkins* -> *Configure System*

[image]

Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository) for more information.

Comment: I had to change "Path to Git executable" and that fixed it

Answer (score 2):

**Possible assumptions for this error**

---

> Make sure you have permission to access this repo on jenkins server
>   machine. you can check it by  putting `git clone http://repo.git` on
>   cmd or terminal whatever os you are using.

---

> Make sure git installed on jenkins server or not,if not then you need
>   to install git on jenkins server first,then try adding git repo to
>   jenkins.

---

> If git is installed on jenkins server machine then check `PATH env
>   variable` has proper git binary executable point location

Comment: good looks - ran into this issue myself and realized I forgot to install git on the new instance