# Automating SSH Key Configuration for Jenkins and GIthub Through Vagrant

Tags: github, ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys, sshd

I am using Vagrant to provision our development environments.

Vagrant does something similar to the following:

1. Installs Jenkins(and Java because its a dependency)
2. ...Other dependency installs....
3. Copies private `id_rsa` SSH key to the `/.ssh` in the `$JENKINS_HOME` which is `/var/lib/jenkins/`
4. Run through script that clones all GitHub repos and builds and deploys projects.

The issue we are having is with `#3` in the list above.

Since we need this to run in a script, we can't manually run the command against GitHub to add the entry to `known_hosts`. So I have tried using the following:

```
sudo -u jenkins ssh-keyscan github.com > /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I have also tried to run this without using the `jenkins` user but was unsuccessful.

Here is the script that the `Vagrantfile` is referencing after Jenkins is installed.

```
#Setup SSH for GitHub
echo "Configuring GitHub SSH Keys..."
if [ ! -d /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh ];
then

#copy private key to $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
sudo cp /vagrant/ssh/id_rsa /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/

#Modify permissions so jenkins user can access
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/
sudo chmod 0600 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh
sudo chmod 0600 /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa

#Add GitHub to known_hosts so it doesn't prompt us
sudo -u jenkins ssh-keyscan github.com > /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts

else
  echo "GitHub SSH Keys already configured..."
fi
```

Am I doing this completely wrong?

My **GOAL** is to be able to copy my private key wherever it needs to go so that I can make a request to GitHub (from Jenkins) without any manual interaction.

My **PROBLEM** is that I can't seem to do this without scripting or CHMODing myself into a permission restricted corner.

I have referenced and seen similar issues such as the post referenced blow

[Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use ssh_config option `GlobalKnownHostsFile`, which is located by default in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` -- if you store here the github public key (using `ssh-keyscan` under root), you don't have to do any magic with chmod and stuff like this.