# Jenkins giving Permission denied (publickey) on adding github repo

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins Github plugin and was using public/private key for one repo, which was working alright. But I got problem when I added another repo, because github doesn't allow sharing public key across multiple repos.

So i integrated jenkins using github token (in Jenkins > manage > configure system and service in github) and removed private/public keys in jenkins server and github. Now when I add repo, I get `Permission denied (publickey)` error (image attached)

How do i integrate multiple github repos with my jenkins server?
[image]

Comment: guys when you down vote, please also explain why. This is does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There is key attached to account of user who's token was added to jenkins. My assumption was it should not have mattered as token was added. But that's not correct.

Added private keys of user who's token was used, in jenkins server and everything returns to normal

Got hint from [Authenticate Jenkins CI for Github private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212304/authenticate-jenkins-ci-for-github-private-repository)